# How do I call a method on an Angularjs directive from outside it's template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angularjs so please bear with me.

I wanted to create a generic wizard that would allow me to walk through a process.  I started by creating a custom directive that handles pretty much all of the "wizarding" stuff ... steps, previous and next, etc.

While the wizard template provides a next and previous button for moving between steps, there may be some actions that would cause the controller/view using the wizard to need to indicate to the wizard that it needs to move forward or backward through a step.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.  I thought maybe $emit or $broadcast might work but I think maybe I'm missing something in regard to scope.

Take a look at this example: [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ibwzeoWV9jR8Fpf7s4tm?p=preview)  It's not pretty but it gives you the idea. What I'd like to be able to do is force a "next" on the wizard when the user selects an order.

Here is the code for my directive:

```
    angular.module("app")
    .directive('rhWizard', [wizard])
    .directive('rhStep', [step]);

function wizard() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function ($scope) {
            var steps = $scope.steps = [];
            $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
            $scope.selectedStep = {};
            $scope.$on('wizNext', function () {
                $scope.next();
            });
            $scope.next = function () {
                var result = $scope.selectedStep.completed();
                if (!result)
                    return;

                var _next = $scope.selectedIndex + 1;
                if (_next < steps.length) {
                    $scope.select(steps[_next]);
                }
            };

            $scope.prev = function () {
                var _next = $scope.selectedIndex - 1;
                if (_next > -1) {
                    $scope.select(steps[_next]);
                }
            }

            $scope.select = function (step) {
                for (var x = 0; x < steps.length; x++) {
                    if (steps[x] == step) {
                        $scope.selectedIndex = x;
                        $scope.selectedStep = step;
                        steps[x].selected = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        steps[x].selected = false;
                    }
                }
            };

            this.addStep = function (step) {
                steps.push(step);
                step.id = steps.length;
                if (steps.length === 1) {
                    $scope.select(step);
                }
            };
        },
        templateUrl: "/Scripts/app/common/rhwizard.html"
    }
};

function step() {
    return {
        require: '^rhWizard',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            completed: '&isComplete',
            nextText: '@',
            prevText: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, wizCtrl) {
            wizCtrl.addStep(scope);
        },
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/common/rhsteps.html'
    };
};
```

And the template code (rhwizard.html):

```
<div class="fuelux">
<div class="wizard">
    <ul class="steps">
        <li ng-class="{active: step.selected, complete: step.id <= selectedIndex }" ng-repeat="step in steps" ng-click="select(step)">
            <span class="badge" ng-class="{'badge-info': step.selected, 'badge-success': step.id <= selectedIndex}" >{{step.id}}</span>{{step.title}}<span class="chevron">
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" ng-click="prev()" ng-disabled="selectedStep.id == 1"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> {{selectedStep.prevText || "Prev"}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" ng-click="next()" ng-disabled="selectedStep.id >= steps.length" >{{selectedStep.nextText || "Next" }} <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="step-content" style="padding-top:20px;" ng-transclude></div>
```

(rhstep.html)

```
<div ng-class="{active: selected}" class="step-pane" ng-transclude>
</div>
```

And a code snippet of it in use:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="orders as vm">
   <rh-wizard>
       <rh-step title="Select an order">
          <div ng-repeat="order in vm.orders" ng-click="next()"></div>
       </rh-step>
       <rh-step title="Select a filter">
          <p>This is the content</p>
       </rh-step>
   </rh-wizard>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this sort of thing is usually handled is by coordinating using a service. The state is managed by the service, and the directive only responds to changes in the state as far as it needs to modify the DOM, hide or display elements, etc. Your controllers outside can also have this service injected and call methods to change the state, such as move the step forward or back, reset the wizard, etc.

It's possible that the service would broadcast events for state changes, such as the step changing, and the directive would listen in on those events to update the view.

Alternately, perhaps in concert with the service, you'd just have a well-known object representing the state of a wizard; the steps, which step is active, which have been completed, etc. Then supply that state as a two-way bound scope item from the controller to the directive. Your directive can then do a deep `$watch` on that scope item for any changes and display them appropriately. Now, I mentioned "in concert with the service". By that I mean the service's actions, such as stepping forward or back, could operate on this wizard state object . That's preferable because you can make well-known actions that you can unit test, rather than leaving it up to the developer to make sure they modify the state object appropriately for the action they wish to express.

The difference between the two suggestions is in the first, the state is completely wrapped up in the service, and it merely notifies consumers when it wants them to react to an action. The latter is a little looser, as the state is coordinated directly between the view's controller and the directive's controller, and if you choose to still have a service, it's only there to make sure operations are done in a consistent and reliable manner. These aren't your only choices, of course. Which is best? It depends on your needs and how complicated your wizard is. With the former, you'll have to remember to reset the state, and if you use multiple wizards, come up with a way for it to know which wizard your view is working with. It seems like it might be worth it for a multi- or complicated wizard system. If the wizard you need is trivial and only used once, the latter might be quick and dirty but good enough.

[I forked your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/m10AFtbQFbsG9pUDf4Qp?p=preview) to include a wizard service that both the directive and any other component can use.

```
.factory('wizard', function() {
  // private state
  var state = {
    steps: [],
    selectedIndex: 0,
  };

  // public methods for manipulating the state
  return {
    next: function() {
      var i = state.selectedIndex + 1;
      if (i < state.steps.length) this.select(state.steps[i]);
    },
    prev: function() {
      var i = state.selectedIndex - 1;
      if (i > -1) this.select(state.steps[i]);
    },
    select: function(step) {
      for(var x = 0; x < state.steps.length; x++){
        var current = state.steps[x];

        if ((angular.isNumber(step) && step === x) || current == step) {
          current.selected = true;
          state.selectedIndex = x;
        } else {
          current.selected = false;
        }
      }
    },
    addStep: function(step) {
      state.steps.push(step);

      if (state.steps.length === 1) this.select(step);
    },
    // lets a consumer get or set the current state. this is how the wizard directive grabs the state which is binds to in the template
    state: function(newState) {
      if (arguments.length === 0) return state;
      if (newState) {
        state = newState;
        if (!state.steps) state.steps = [];
        if (isNaN(state.selectedIndex)) state.selectedIndex = 0;
      }
    }
  };
})
```